# The sum of $\frac{k^{2}}{k-1}$ from 6 to 12

Tags: summation

Can you evaluate this sum by using the properties of the sigma notation ? Or I must develop this and evaluate them one by one ?

Comment: You can write $\frac{k^2}{k-1}=\frac{k^2-1+1}{k-1}=k+1+\frac{1}{k-1}$ and then the sum as $S=\sum_{k=6}^{12}{(k+1)} + \sum_{k=6}^{12}{\frac{1}{k-1}}$. The first summation is easy enough, bu the second is a harmonic sum, which has no exact closed-form solution in the general case. You will need to add the terms one by one for the second summation.

Comment: Ok, so I guess my problem is asking me to do the sum one by one for the initial form also because I thought I would be able to use properties to simplify the work. THank you!